# how do I use StartWith() rx operator but only if sequence is not empty?

Tags: reactive-programming

I have a rx observable and I need to add one certain item but only if observable emit at least one item.

I went trough all the operators but couldn't find appropriate. The closest is [StartWith](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/startwith.html) but according to diagram it emits item immediately and does not take in count next items.

Is it possible to achieve this by combining it with some other operators ?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I have been trying to do the same and the only thing I came up with is not very reactive:

```
    Observable.just(1, 2, 3)
    .toList()
    .flatMap(items -> {
      if (items.size() > 0) {
        items.add(0, 0);
      }
      return Observable.from(items);
    })
```

It's far from perfect and will not work in case of "hot" observable.